# Cannot set non-nullable LiveData value to null

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, kotlin-null-safety

The error from the title is returned for the following code, which makes no sense

```
private val _error = MutableLiveData<String?>()
val error: LiveData<String?> get() = _error


_error.postValue(null)  //Error Cannot set non-nullable LiveData value to null [NullSafeMutableLiveData]
```

parameter `String` of `_error`  is obviously nullable, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is this a compile time error ? What version of arch component you are using ?

Comment: Try to invalidate the cache or update the dependencies, there is no problem with your code.

Comment: @ADM yes compile time Lint error for release build only, debug build works fine. Android Studio also shows this error. Version is different for some components, lyfecycle-livedata is 2.3.0.beta01

Comment: @VincentSit everything is up to date, invalidate cache doesnt help

Comment: Not sure if its the same but they have fixed an issue in recent release `2.3.0-alpha07` . [See this](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#2.3.0-alpha07) . Just an advise its better to use Stable version of libraries in production. for a solution now you can ignore lint check

Comment: @ADM thank you, good to know

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This appears to be related to a bug already reported against `androidx.lifecycle` pre-release of 2.3.0  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/169249668.

Workarounds I have found:

1. turn off or reduce severity of `NullSafeMutableLiveData` in

`build.gradle`

```
android {
  ...
  lintOptions {
    disable 'NullSafeMutableLiveData'
  }
}
```

or `lint.xml` in root dir

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lint>
    <issue id="NullSafeMutableLiveData" severity="warning" />
</lint>
```

2. Do the work for `MutableLiveData` encapsulation via backing properties dance (which really hurts my eyes).

```
class ExampleViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _data1 = MutableLiveData<Int>()
    val data1: LiveData<Int> = _data1

    private val _data2 = MutableLiveData<Int?>()
    val data2: LiveData<Int?> = _data2

    fun funct() {
        _data1.value = 1
        _data2.value = null
    }
}
```

Comment: It hurts my eyes too, consider upvoting this https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-14663

Answer (score 3):

This has been fixed in version 2.3.1.

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#version_231_2

Comment: Nope, it's going to be fixed in v2.4.0 instead: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/169249668#comment8

Comment: 2.4.0 is out, and the issue is still there.

Answer (score 1):

Add NullSafeMutableLiveData in your function,

```
@Suppress("NullSafeMutableLiveData")
fun clearBeforeData(){
    _articles.postValue(null)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems fixed in lifecycle 2.4.0-SNAPSHOT.
Please wait for the official release.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was coming in `2.3.0` also but after upgrading to `2.4.0` it is not coming.

Answer (score 0):

I think this has been fixed in `version 2.4.1`

this is my working solution

```
private val _roomDataObserver: MutableLiveData<List<Resource<ModelClass?>>?> = MutableLiveData()
val roomDataObserver: LiveData<List<Resource<ModelClass?>>?>
    get() = _classroomDataObserver

 override fun onCleared() {
    super.onCleared()
    Log.d("VIEWMODEL", "CLEARED")
    _roomDataObserver.value = null
}
```